# Patching GHOST Vulnerability # CVE-2015-0235 SLES 11 SP3

Tags: patch-management, sles11

I need to upgrade a SLES 11 SP3 server for the new ghost vulnerability that has been discovered.

According to http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cve-2015-0235-patch-ghost-on-debian-ubuntu-fedora-centos-rhel-linux/ I should be able to run zypper although this doesn't work as it says there are no packages found.

However, Zypper isn't any good to me any as the server I need to upgrade doesn't have direct access to the internet, so I need an offline install, I guess an RPM would be best. I've had a look at the novel repos but it doesn't seem to have been updated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Novel account?

Regarding [this link](https://download.suse.com/Download?buildid=Go6KY9fObnM~) you can download the files.